# Using urlparse to remove a certain string?

Tags: python, urlparse

I have this URL:

```
www.domain.com/a/b/c/d,authorised=false.html
```

and I want to convert it into

```
www.domain.com/a/b/c/d.html
```

Please note I am using python 2.7.

```
from urlparse import urlparse

url = "www.domain.com/a/b/c/d,athorised=false.html_i_location=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain.com%2Fcms%2Fs%2F0%2Ff416e134-2484-11e4-ae78-00144feabdc0.html%3Fsiteedition%3Dintl&siteedition=intl&_i_referer=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain.com%2Fhome%2Fus"

o = urlparse(url)
url = o.hostname + o.path
print url
```

returns `www.domain.com/a/b/c/d,authorised=false.html` but I don't know how to remove `authorised=false` part from the URL

Comment: Here you go: http://dpaste.com/3BY70EK

Comment: @Sushi For future reference, it is easier for people to respond if you include the code inline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import re
print re.sub(r',.+\.', '.', 'www.domain.com/a/b/c/d,authorised=false.html')

# www.domain.com/a/b/c/d.html
```